# PowerShell: Accessing Key name without ForEach and GetEnumerator

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have an **OrderedDictionaryKeyCollection** comprising the following values:

```
[0] = "Alpha"
[1] = "Bravo"
[2] = "Charlie"
[3] = "Delta"
[4] = "Echo"
```

How do I access **Key[2]** value directly ("Charlie") without using **ForEach** and **GetEnumerator**?

Comment: `@($foo)[2]` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object -Index`:

```
$OrderedDictionary = [ordered]@{
  Alpha   = ""
  Bravo   = ""
  Charlie = ""
  Delta   = ""
  Echo    = ""
}
$SecondKey = $OrderedDictionary.Keys |Select -Index 2
```